# Get data from SQL table by linq-to-sql using data from collection

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm using entity framework to connect to database from my application. I have table in SQL, named **Orders**. It contains such fields as: TransactionId, ParticipantId and is linked to **Transactions** table which has one to many connection to **Participants** table. I need to get data from it using List of classes with such properties: TransactionId, ParticipantId, OrganizationId. Linq must meet such conditions: `(orders.TransactionId == TransactionId && orders.ParticipantId == ParticipantId && orders.Transaction.Participants.Any(x=> x.Id == OrganizationId))`. This should be done by one query, not by multiple, so, please don't recommend foreach or smth like that.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @NetMage, you mean what queries I have used?

Answer (score 0):

Like @NetMage said, generally we need examples. Assuming that you've got a dbcontext set up, the ask is pretty simple:

```
public static void GetData(int transactionId, int participantId, int organizationId)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var query =
            (
                from t in db.Transactions
                from o in db.Orders
                    .Where(w => w.TransactionId == t.TransactionId)
                from p in db.Participants
                    .Where(w => w.TransactionId == t.TransactionId)
                where t.TransactionId = transactionId &&
                    o.ParticipantId = participantId
                select new { Order = o, Transaction = t, Participant = p}
            );
    }
}
```

Again since we don't have a lot of information here it's hard to do more. You should be able to take it from there. I know I didn't use the organizationId filter, but since I don't know the target shape of the data I'm not sure what the best path would be